# MySQL Percentage Share by Date

Tags: mysql

I have the following structure:

```
    +-------------+---------+------------+
| impressions | device  | dates      |
+-------------+---------+------------+
|        4788 | desktop | 2019-04-29 |
|        6336 | mobile  | 2019-04-29 |
|        2798 | tablet  | 2019-04-29 |
|        4911 | desktop | 2019-04-30 |
|        6005 | mobile  | 2019-04-30 |
|        3103 | tablet  | 2019-04-30 |
|        5053 | desktop | 2019-05-01 |
|        6131 | mobile  | 2019-05-01 |
|        2873 | tablet  | 2019-05-01 |
|        4446 | desktop | 2019-05-02 |
|        6345 | mobile  | 2019-05-02 |
|        2864 | tablet  | 2019-05-02 |
```

How would I calculate the percentage share of each device for each date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by date and with conditional aggregation:

```
select
  dates,
  round(100.0 * sum(case when device = 'desktop' then impressions end) / sum(impressions), 2) as desktop,
  round(100.0 * sum(case when device = 'mobile' then impressions end) / sum(impressions), 2) as mobile,
  round(100.0 * sum(case when device = 'tablet' then impressions end) / sum(impressions), 2) as tablet
from tablename
group by dates;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kG8TKcHrvN7Fqk2GPYD8SS/0).
Results:

```
| dates      | desktop | mobile | tablet |
| ---------- | ------- | ------ | ------ |
| 2019-04-29 | 34.39   | 45.51  | 20.1   |
| 2019-04-30 | 35.03   | 42.83  | 22.13  |
| 2019-05-01 | 35.95   | 43.62  | 20.44  |
| 2019-05-02 | 32.56   | 46.47  | 20.97  |
```

Comment: Thanks - I always forget about case. Nice solution